# Get ALL Edittext value from ListView

Tags: java, android

I want to get all the value from ListView and store it into an Array, it works fine for String tag but String location is throwing null exception.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

In my ListView, there may be a empty value for location Edittext. But textview for tag is not null.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


for(int i = 0;i < listView.getChildCount() ; i++){
    View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
    String tag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtviewdata)).getText().toString();
    String location = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.location)).getText().toString();
    list.add(tag);
    list.add(location);
}
System.out.println(list);
}
});
```

Please help thank you very much.

Comment: Refer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050948/11560232. This might answer your question.

Comment: Please post your list item xml

Comment: try to cast as TextView `String location = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location)).getText().toString();`